# ¿Cómo evitar la reordenación de una tabla después de actualizar uno de sus registros?

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

Cada vez que modifico un registro la tabla se reordena, situando en último lugar el registro recién modificado.

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {                             // actualiza la lectura del contador
    req.lectura.lectura_actual = req.body.lectura.lectura_actual;
    req.lectura.texto = req.body.lectura.texto;

    req.lectura.save({fields: ["lectura_actual", "texto"]})
        .then(function() {res.redirect('/partes/' + req.params.parteId);})
        .catch(function(error) {next(error)});


};
```

Necesito que "lectura" se guarde en el mismo orden que se visualiza, pero como decía, se lo lleva al final de la tabla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mayoría de motores de bases de datos no aseguran un orden específico, éstas se ordenan por decisión del motor conforme ellos quieran para asegurar la consistencia de datos. Por otro lado, el orden es irrelevante porque, en tu gestor, puedes ordenar por cualquier columna.

Si necesitas de un orden en específico al recuperar los datos, **jamás confíes** en el criterio del motor de base de datos, en su lugar, se debe realizar un `ORDER BY` para ordenar por la columna que se requiera.

```
return Modelo.findAll({
  order: '<campo> <orientación>'
});
```

Donde:

- campo es el campo del modelo (no de la columna)
- orientación la orientación del ordenado (ASC/DESC)

Mi otra pregunta es: ¿Por qué usas un middleware para actualizar? Ten en cuenta que, un middleware está pensado para siempre ejecutarse antes de que se ejecute la función asociada a una ruta en específico, así que, ese middleware será ejecutado múltiples veces, lo cual hace operaciones innecesarias. Debería ser una ruta normal:

```
app.put('/:id', (request, response) => {
  let id = request.params.id;
  // actualizar
});
```

Si tu propósito es hacer que `lectura` sea un objeto compartido a través de todos los clientes, entonces puedes encapsular dicho objeto en un módulo y modificarlo.

```
/* shared/reading.js */
const lectura = /* valor inicial */;

const LecturaHandler = () => {
  return {
    get () { return lectura; },
    update ({ lectura_actual, texto }, cb) {
      lectura.lectura_actual = lectura_actual;
      lectura.texto = texto;
      return lectura.save();
    }
  };
}

const instance = LecturaHandler();
Object.freeze(instance);
export default instance;
```

Y actualizarías así:

```
const LecturaHandler = require('./shared/reading.js');

app.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
  LecturaHandler.update(req.body, (promise) => {
    promise
      .then(lectura => {
        res.redirect(`/partes/${req.params.parteId}`);
      })
      .catch(err => res.jsonp(err.errors));
  });
});
```

Comment: Es cierto, es cosa de PostgreSQL. Se soluciona con ORDER BY.

Comment: Sobre el segundo consejo comentar que la aplicación está hecha en express, y todo con rutas y middleware.